# use GMM and EM algorithm for image segmentation java

Tags: java, image-processing, image-segmentation, gmm

I tried to find some good definition that will give me an idea about how can I implement the `EM algorithm` for `image segmentation` but I found nothing, I have also searched in other programming language as python, matlab, ... but all exemple I find they use defined methods. I hope some here could help me with some code exemple for implement this method in `java` for `RGB images`, thanks.

you can find info about this method her : [her](http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~vplab/courses/DVP/PDF/gmm.pdf)

Comment: Why post this picture? How is it related to your question?

Comment: that is the function how should I implement. it use for calculating the probability of each gaussien.

Comment: I do not understand french.

Comment: check this line http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~vplab/courses/DVP/PDF/gmm.pdf

Comment: I am not willing to read a 15-page PDF to answer your question, sorry.